# How to change the default 404 error page with custom page from pages app

Tags: magnolia

I am new to Magnolia.

I have created an Error page in Pages App. Now I would like to change the Default 404 error page with my error page. How do I do this?

Comment: Related: Internationalization of 404 pages http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002197/magnolia-cms-internationalization-of-404-pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Since magnolia 3.5 (magnolia internal error page)

Please open your `web.xml` file and update `error-page` tag like the following code,

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/website-country/error-page</location>
</error-page>.
```

Here `/website-country/error-page` is the custom page which is available in **Pages App**.

---

#### Resources

[wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/How+to+setup+a+custom+404+handler](https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/How+to+setup+a+custom+404+handler)

[documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Custom+error+page](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Custom+error+page)